# (PHP) tcp socket over proxy

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, minecraft

I connect to the Minecraft server via tcp, how do I use a proxy server
I know how to use a proxy for HTTP requests, but I don’t really understand how to do it for TCP

```
$data = "\x00";
$data .= makeVarInt($proto);
$data .= pack('c', strlen($ip)) . $ip;
$data .= pack('n', $port);
$data .= "\x02";
$handshake = pack('c', strlen($data)) . $data;
$nick = generateRandomString(5)."_RAGE_". generateRandomString(5);

    //Create TCP socket
    $socket = @stream_socket_client("tcp://$ip:$port", $errno, $errstr, 10);

    //Check for errors
    if ($errno > 0) {
        echo "ERROR: " . $errstr . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }



    //Send login handshake packet
    fwrite($socket, $handshake);

    //Make login start packet
    $data = "\x00";
    $data .= pack('c', strlen($nick)) . $nick;
    $data = pack('c', strlen($data)) . $data;

    //Send login start packet
    fwrite($socket,  $data);
```